# Create a object in C# without the use of new Keyword?

Tags: c#, new-operator

Is there a way to create a object without the use of new keyword in C# some thing like      class.forname();
 in java.

I want to dynamically create a object of a class. The object creation may depend on the users input.
I have a base class x and there are 5 subclasses (a,b,c,d,e) of it. My user input will be a or b or...e class names. Using this I need to create a object of that class.How do I do this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538304/is-it-possible-to-create-an-object-instance-based-on-a-string-value-denoting-its

Comment: Agree wit Gaz.., Please provide more information. There are rare cases where you want to do something like this.

Comment: Same thing as Object.GetType().  What that has to do with the *new* operator is hard to guess.  I guess you'll be interested in Activator.CreateInstance().

Comment: I want to dynamically create a object of a class. The object creation may depend on the users input.

Comment: Who upvotes questions like this? "This question shows research effort;" (oh?) "it is useful and clear" (oh?).

Comment: If all you want to do is create a different type depending on various pieces of user input surely you just need to implement a Factory or Builder, but it's hard to guess without knowing how the class being created needs to be derived from the input.

Comment: I have a base class x and there are 5 subclasses (a,b,c,d,e) of it. My user input will be a or b or...e using this I need to create a object of that class.How do I do this

Comment: it depends on their constructor. if they accepts the same parameters, you could think about using a Factory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use the [Activator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx).

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
object[] parameters = new object[]{1, "hello", "world" };
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
MyClass myClass = obj as MyClass;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is significantly slower, and should not be used **just** to avoid the `new` operator

Comment: I see a `new` keyword in there. :P

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a static class?

```
static class Foo
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.Bar()");
    }
}
```

You can then call `Foo.Bar();`.

But you'd better explain what you're trying to do. "Creating an object without the use of `new`" is a solution you came up with for a problem you're having. Just explaining that problem might reveal an easier way to solve it.

Edit: you seem to need a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29), given your comment "I want to dynamically create a object of a class. The object creation may depend on the users input".

So something like this may be sufficient:

```
static class PizzaFactory
{
    static Pizza CreatePizza(String topping)
    {
        if (topping == "cheese")
        {
            return new CheesePizza();
        }
        else if (topping == "salami")
        {
            return new SalamiPizza();
        }
    }
}

class Pizza { }
class CheesePizza : Pizza { }
class SalamiPizza : Pizza { }
```

Throwing in an Interface or Abstract class where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `default` keyword, but it will only result in an instance for value types:

```
var s = default(string); // null
var i = default(int);    // integer (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Activator class is very slow you can use the lambda expressions look at this
[Activator alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432026/activator-createinstance-performance-alternative)

Answer (score -4):

You may be able to do it with

```
typeof(MyType)
```

Comment: Sorry -- downvoted baecause the answer doesn't make it clear how you might do it.