# How to create a new object in C# Hybridizer CUDA code

Tags: c#, hybridizer

As mentioned in [Hybridizer's documentation,](http://www.altimesh.com/get-started/) you can't use the new x() method of instantiating an object in Hybridizer CUDA code.

I tried to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049193/create-a-object-in-c-sharp-without-the-use-of-new-keyword), but it would give an error related to the use of typeof(x)

```
[ERROR] : 0X6079 : EnrichMethodDependencyGraph failed for method System.Type -- Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I also tried just using it like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance<x>()
```

But that would just give a different error that I can find no information on online.

```
[ERROR] : 0X6079 : EnrichMethodDependencyGraph failed for method System.Activator -- Exception: System.ArgumentException: A BadImageFormatException has been thrown while parsing the signature. This is likely due to lack of a generic context. Ensure genericTypeArguments and genericMethodArguments are provided and contain enough context. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Instantiating an object should be a very simple thing, but I can't find any way to do it online... Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

Using `typeof(x)` requires object type information, which is not made available on the GPU side. `Activator.CreateInstance<x>` is essentially the same thing.

The limitation does not come from the `new` keyword, it comes from the fat that garbage collection is not implemented on the GPU side.

Possible workarounds for your issue:

1. Your type can be replaced by primitives : you may allocate array of primitive types on the GPU.
2. You may define your own allocator based on a preallocated array of instances and an atomic index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my needs for this cannot be fulfilled by primitives so 1 will not work for me. Can you explain how I would do 2?